# Prevent screensaver depending on activity

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have an .NET Core app displaying data using a raspberry PI (Raspberry PI OS/Raspbian).
I'd like to prevent raspberry's screensaver (or sleep mode) only when there's something to display.
Which command can I send ? What mecanism can I use ?

Comment: So, if there's nothing to display you will prevent sleep mode and when there's something to display you will let the pi sleep. Are you sure, you don't want the opposite?

Comment: Oups, you're right!

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @DanielA.White Raspberry PI OS (Raspbian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do so :

- First, I permanently deactivate screen-saver with *autostart* script and commands :

  @xset s off

  @xset -dpms
- Next, I only "play" with hdmi activation when I need it:

  ```
  - `tvservice -p` to activate HDMI display
  - `tvservice -o` to deactivate HDMI display
  ```

To send command, I use this :

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "/usr/bin/bash", Arguments = "-c \" COMMAND_TO_SEND \""}).WaitForExit();
```